# installing cx_freeze on ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, cx-freeze

i have kubuntu 15.10 with python2.7 and python 3.4m installed
if i install cxfreeze with sudo apt-get cx_freeze it is installed with no issues but the problem is when i compile my python modules the are compiled for python2.7 not python 3
So i am trying to build cx_freeze from source and i am facing this error when i run `sudo python3 setup.py build`

here's the error

```
adding base module named weakref 
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict
prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format
security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
I/usr/include/python3.4m -c source/bases/Console.c -o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/source/bases/Console.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread build/temp.linux-x86_64
3.4/source/bases/Console.o -L/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64
linux-gnu -lpython3.4 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64
3.4/cx_Freeze/bases/Console -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,
Bsymbolic-functions -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lrt -lexpat -L/usr/lib
-lz -lexpat -s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1'
```

Comment: That looks pretty broken. Have you tried installing the python 3 version of cx_freeze with `pip` instead?

Comment: I usually avoid using apt-get install with python packages, because the versions installed from the debian/ubuntu repo sometimes is much older than the most recent one from pypi.

Comment: Has `zlib1g-dev` package been installed?

Answer (score 2):

Install `zlib1g-dev` :
`sudo apt install zlib1g-dev`

then install `cx_freeze` for python:
`pip install cx_freeze`

I've tried that on Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.6 and worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48601771/installing-cx-freeze-on-ubuntu-returns-error-code-1).  As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609269/cx-freeze-build-error) answer you just need to install the dependencies first:

```
pip3 install zlib1g-dev
```

Then `sudo python3 setup.py build`