# cx_Freeze build error?

Tags: python, pip, cx-freeze

I am trying to create a binary from a python,flask and boto3 app. I am having trouble running the `pip install cx_Freeze` command too work. I am getting the following error :

It seems to be not fetching the right system libraries. Also, can anyone suggest any tools to package python apps into binaries?

```
  Failed building wheel for cx-Freeze
  Running setup.py clean for cx-Freeze
Failed to build cx-Freeze
Installing collected packages: cx-Freeze
  Running setup.py install for cx-Freeze ... error
    Complete output from command /home/shaswat.g/.virtualenvs/flask_app/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,     tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yLvkz9/cx-Freeze/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',     open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install     --record /tmp/pip-kKRaSM-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile     --install-headers /home/shaswat.g/.virtualenvs/flask_app/include/site/python2.7/cx-Freeze:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze/dist.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze/main.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze/macdist.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze/finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze/setupwriter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze/windist.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze/hooks.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze
    copying cx_Freeze/freezer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze/initscripts/SharedLibSource.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze/initscripts/SharedLib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze/initscripts/ConsoleSetLibPath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/initscripts
    copying cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/initscripts
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/relimport
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/relimport/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/relimport
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/relimport/relimport.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/relimport
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/service
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/service/Config.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/service
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/service/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/service
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/service/ServiceHandler.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/service
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/openpyxl
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/openpyxl/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/openpyxl
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/openpyxl/test_openpyxl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/openpyxl
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/simple
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/simple/hello.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/simple
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/simple/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/simple
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/matplotlib
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/matplotlib/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/matplotlib
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/matplotlib/matplotlib_eg.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/    matplotlib
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/PyQt4
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/PyQt4/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/PyQt4
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/PyQt4/PyQt4app.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/PyQt4
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/advanced
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/advanced/advanced_1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/advanced
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/advanced/advanced_2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/advanced
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/advanced/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/advanced
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/asmodule
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/asmodule/asmodule.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/asmodule
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/asmodule/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/asmodule
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/zope
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/zope/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/zope
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/zope/qotd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/zope
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/Tkinter
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/Tkinter/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/Tkinter
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/Tkinter/SimpleTkApp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/Tkinter
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/wx
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/wx/setup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/wx
    copying cx_Freeze/samples/wx/wxapp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/samples/wx
    running build_ext
    building 'cx_Freeze.util' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/source
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing     -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-HVkOs2/python2.7-2.7.13=.     -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c source/util.c -o     build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/source/util.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing     -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/    python2.7-HVkOs2/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-z,relro     -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-HVkOs2/python2.7-2.7.13=.     -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/source/util.o -o build/    lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/util.so
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/source/bases
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing     -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-HVkOs2/python2.7-2.7.13=.     -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c source/bases/    Console.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/source/bases/Console.o
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/bases
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/source/bases/Console.o -L/usr/lib/python2.7/    config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cx_Freeze/bases/Console -Xlinker     -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -L/usr/lib -lz -s
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/shaswat.g/.virtualenvs/flask_app/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yLvkz9/cx-Freeze/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-kKRaSM-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/shaswat.g/.virtualenvs/flask_app/include/site/python2.7/cx-Freeze" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yLvkz9/cx-Freeze/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do

```
sudo apt install zlib1g-dev
```

I was trying to install `cx-freeze` to convert some python code to an exe but the problem was `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz` just like you. The file being fetched is compressed (`cx_Freeze-5.1.1.tar.gz`) so you need `zlib`. Of course use `pip3` for python3.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "sudo apt install zlib1g-dev"?

Comment: Yeah exactly; The pip version doesn't work for some reason but I could have sworn it worked at the time I was writing that.

Comment: Thanks. The sudo apt version did work, but then I just had to give up on trying to build the package in Python. Thanks for the input though, this was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

`pip` never installs *system* libraries, it only concerns itself with *Python libs*.

It seems you need to install `zlib` before installing cx_Freeze.

Another tool to generate binaries is [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Comment: Still can't seem to compile my code. The app that I am making uses flask and boto3, so can you point me, to which _system libraries_ I will need as well?

This although seems like a topic for a different question altogether.

Comment: I don't know. My installer installed all necessary system libraries when I installed Python. When I feel I need something more I experiment and install required packages one by one.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me on centos8

```
yum install gcc
yum install python3-devel
pip install wheel
pip install importlib-metadata
pip install patchelf
pip3 install cx-Freeze
```